# Displaying images for only a specific period of time in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

So I just came to know about pygame and thought it would be cool to use it to make a simple space invaders game.So in my code https://pastebin.com/eksFCbYr I want the image "bullet.png" to be displayed on the screen only during the duration of the spacebar being pressed.But it doesnt seem to work.
I first thought that it may be because the image is being drawn below another image.So I changed the positions of the images concerned such that they dont overlap.But that seems to have had no effect,indicating that is not the problem.
Could someone identify what mistake i have made in my code.Also please tell me if there are any better ways to do this.

Thanks`

```
            m = 2 
bull = pygame.image.load("bullet.png")
t=True
while t:
    screen.fill((50, 50, 50))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:

            t = False

 #keydown statement
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                n = 1
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            p = -1
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:

                m = 0
 #keyup statement
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or pygame.K_LEFT:
               n = 0
               p = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                m = 1
    if m == 0:

        screen.blit(bull, (ab, 100))

    background()
    player1(ab, bc)

    ab += n+p


    if ab <= 0:
        ab = 0
    if ab >= 468:
        ab = 468

    pygame.display.update()
```

{This is my first ever post and also i am a complete newbie to python(and even programming for that matter).So please forgive me if my question is not formatted in the right way.}

Answer (score 0):

The reason the bullet is not showing up on screen is because of the keyup statement. Because as it says in your code, the moment the Space key is unpressed, the value 'm' is back to 1 again (m = 1) and the if statement wont be executed. Then if what I said is the problem, I suggest you define a shoot function that blits the bullet on screen and moves it too. It's also better to use the following code instead using keyup or keydown statements:

```
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_Space]:
        player.shoot()
```

This might help with the problem. shoot() is the function I mentioned but you can use some other method that you're comfortable with.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions .i will try them out